# angularjs filter remaining dropdown choices after a selection

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I were creating a system that allowed for multiple field searches and wanted to do this via drop down (similar to Redmine), how could I implement that?  With the specific part being, once I select the field "foo" and I click a button that says "Add another field" I would not be able to select "foo" again?

```
initial fields: {"foo","bar","baz"}  
select fields.foo  
add another field
remaining fields = {"bar","baz"}
```

Let me know if clarification is required.

I found a drop down example [here](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/select).

**CLARIFICATION**

Let "foo" be an integer
Let "bar" be a date
Let "baz" be a string

If the user adds the field "bar" I would provide a calendar picker widget.
If the user selects "foo" I ensure the number is a valid integer.
If the user selects "baz" I check to make sure it is a valid string.

Therefore, each selection will exhibit certain behavior based on the field selection, so the user must select each field individually via the "Add another field" button.

Comment: Hi, sorry if I misunderstood your requirement, but if you want to allow the user for multiple field searches, adding just one dropdown will restrict your initial idea. You may want to include several dropdowns so the user can choose as many fields he/she wants. So the first will show the three options, a second one only two, and a third just the last one. You should read all the selected options, and then do your search.

Comment: @Guillermo so your proposal is to have a multi-field select within the single drop down?  What if some of the fields are only numerics and others are not?  How could I allow them to enter dynamic text?

Answer (score 3):

I've done this very thing many times.  Here's a snippet from my own code.  The code was used to allow commercial contractors to select "affiliations" for their company.

In my HTML view:

```
<select class="input-full" ng-model="currAff" ng-options="aff for aff in availableAffs | filter:notAlreadyAdded"></select>
```

Note the `filter:notAlreadyAdded` portion above.

In my controller:

```
$scope.notAlreadyAdded = function(aff){
    // search through all the affiliations that were previously added
    // if the given "aff" is in the previously-added list, return false
    // else, return true
};
```

Using the `filter:notAlreadyAdded` filter for the ng-options on a select will loop through each item in the array of options and will pass that item to the given function.  You can then use that item to do whatever testing you want and then you simply return a boolean that tells angular if it should include that item in the list of possible options in the future.

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: so in the notAlreadyAdded function I would pass the "added" list and subtract it from my "known" list?

Comment: You shouldn't need to pass the "added" or "known" lists because they should already be available through your `$scope` right?  So you should just be able to say loop through your `$scope.added` array (or whatever you've called it) and check to see if the given `aff` is in that `added` array.  If it is, just return `false` and if not, return `true`.

Comment: ah gotcha, most appreciated.  I will go and test this out shortly.